# Rooting Monstera cuttings are yellowing

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, cuttings, monstera

I occasionally trim my very healthy monstera and root the cuttings. I’ve done this so many times and never had issues. I recently made three cuttings (2-3 leaves per cutting), stuck them in water, and they’ve been yellowing and I presume dying slowing over the past few weeks. Two of the cuttings are growing roots as expected, but I’m afraid the plant won’t survive regardless, if it loses the leaves.

[image]

Some leaves look healthier than others, but they’re all showing signs of yellowing. What’s causing this? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rooting cuttings not always yields a 100% success rate. There can be losses due to rot or other conditions that persisted even before the cuttings were taken. In your case I think the problem is related to the fact of winter. Lower light and probably lower humidity conditions are not ideal for propagation. A plant without roots will struggle to keep its leaves, especially if there are multiple of them.

On the other hand loosing all of the leaves is not always a problem with *Monstera deliciosa* as it can root and put out new leaves even from a bare stem. But given it is winter now, it will take more time compared to a cutting that has leaves.

Such cuttings are often called "wet sticks" and I had luck with them multiple times in the past in case of *Monstera deliciosa* and other *Monsteras* as well.

Here is a picture of one:
[image]